# Javafx. Как запустить потоки после нажатия кнопки

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx, button, imageview

После нажатия на кнопку запускаются два потока: первый меняет картинку у кнопки, второй -- цикл.

Я хочу, чтобы после нажатия сначала менялась картинка и показывалась на экране, а после запускался цикл, но всё завершается в один момент.

Я могу увидеть изменение картинки только после завершения цикла.

```java
myButton.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
                imageView.setFitHeight(my_button_height - 16);
                imageView.setFitWidth(my_button_width - 16);
                myButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffffff00; ");
                myButton.setGraphic(imageView);
            }
        });
        thread.run();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
                    System.out.println(i);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        thread1.run();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для запуска *отдельного* потока в общем случае используется метод `Thread::start`.

Если создать экземпляр класса-потомка `Thread` и просто вызвать его метод `run`, то код этого метода будет выполняться в *основном* потоке, то есть, в представленной реализации нет параллельного выполнения двух дополнительных потоков, а обычное последовательное выполнение, причем запуск кода `thread1` вызовет "подвисание" после нажатия кнопки длительностью `7.5 с = 15 * 500 мс`.

Также при создании потоков можно было использовать лямбду `Thread t = new Thread(() -> {...})`, а не многословное "старомодное" объявление.

Кроме того, в данном случае первый поток пытается изменить UI в JavaFX, что разрешено только из потока JavaFX приложения ([*JavaFX application thread*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#A1107438)).

Поэтому первый поток следует запускать при помощи [`Platform::runLater(Runnable r)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-), соответственно, не потребуется вызывать `Thread::join`.

Исправленный код:

```java
myButton.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
            imageView.setFitHeight(my_button_height - 16);
            imageView.setFitWidth(my_button_width - 16);
            myButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffffff00; ");
            myButton.setGraphic(imageView);
        });
        // нет изменения UI, отдельная переменная `thread1` не нужна
        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
                System.out.println(i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        })
        .start(); // можно просто вызвать метод Thread::start
    }
});
```

---

Связанные вопросы на основном SO:

- [How can I create Thread in javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219165/how-can-i-create-thread-in-javafx)
- [Execute task in background in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165251/) -- здесь рассматривается пример более сложного взаимодействия фонового потока с UI при помощи создания `Task<Void>`.

Comment: К сожалению, выбросился Exception:
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-3

Comment: @Lipe, обновил ответ, первый поток надо будет запускать при помощи [`Platform::runLater(Runnable r)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-)